# Telegraf agent not running tail command in Exec input

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I am trying to record log history of a VM using telegraf `[[inputs.exec]]`.
I have configured it as follows:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
commands = ["sh /etc/telegraf/commands.sh"]
data_format = "influx"
data_type = "string"
```

`commands.sh` file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
telgu="$(id -u telegraf )"
log="$(tail -n 10 /var/log/auth.log | grep --line-buffered snoopy | grep -v $telgu)"
base="$(echo  $log |openssl base64)"
echo commands,tag=commands log="\"${base}\""
```

When running script manually it works fine, however when executed with telegraf no data is received; I am getting the following data:

```
commands,host=localhost,serverid=08d9ea88-16ba-414f-88d68b6f110035c7,tag=commands log="Cg==" 1556957280000000000
```

Comment: Please re-run the script manually, and paste the output again; it looks like the data you've pasted is from another version of the script.

Comment: The `1556957280000000000` at the end of the output is optional, and if what you want in `InfluxDB` is a number, you don't need to surround it with "double-quotes".

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/telegraf.log`?